# When using Jenkins with Maven builds, how do I override the naming convention of artifacts having the version from the pom file appended to them?

Tags: maven, jenkins, war, pom.xml, artifacts

I'm currently building Alfresco using maven. My main pom has several sub poms within them, each with a  that that's just SNAPSHOT-1.0 for now.

If I do an mvn install from the command line, I get war files in /target/.war, but when I build in Jenkins, I get artefacts named as -SNAPSHOT-1.0.war. In the workspace, they're still .war, but Jenkins creates artefacts by appending the maven version for some reason.

If I want to deploy these wars out to an application server (right now I'm limited to ssh deployments), I need to rename them first so they get deployed with the right context root.

Is there anyway to make the artefacts available to other build jobs as their normal names without the version number? Right now I just have a job that copies artefacts and renames them before deployment, but I was thinking there had to be a cleaner way.

Updated: main pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>nz.net.example</groupId>
<artifactId>dept-alfresco</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Quickstart of Alfresco and Share with DB and runner embedded</name>
<description>This All-in-One project allows to manage all the components involved in Alfresco development (Repo, Share, Solr, AMPs) in one project</description>
<packaging>pom</packaging>    

<parent>
    <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<!-- 
   | SDK properties have sensible defaults in the SDK parent,
   | but you can override the properties below to use another version. 
   | For more available properties see the alfresco-sdk-parent POM. 
   -->
<properties>
    <alfresco.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.groupId>
    <alfresco.version>4.2.c</alfresco.version>
    <app.log.root.level>WARN</app.log.root.level>
    <alfresco.data.location>alf_data_dev</alfresco.data.location>
    <alfresco.port>8080</alfresco.port> 
    <share.port>8080</share.port>
    <!-- This controls which properties will be picked in src/test/properties for embedded run -->
    <env>local</env>

    <!-- Build Information to be injected during Jenkins build process -->
    <build.date>Not Built with Jenkins</build.date>
    <jenkins.buildNo>Not Built with Jenkins</jenkins.buildNo>
    <jenkins.buildURL>Not Built with Jenkins</jenkins.buildURL>
    <jenkins.job>Not Built with Jenkins</jenkins.job>
    <git.branch>Not Built with Jenkins</git.branch>
    <git.commit>Not Built with Jenkins</git.commit>
</properties>

<!-- Here we realize the connection with the Alfresco selected platform (e.g.version and edition) -->
<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
      <!-- This will import the dependencyManagement for all artifacts in the selected Alfresco plaftorm
           (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)
           NOTE: You still need to define dependencies in your POM, but you can omit version as it's enforced by this dependencyManagement.
           NOTE: It defaults to the latest version this SDK pom has been tested with, but alfresco version can/should be overridden in your project's pom   
       -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>alfresco-platform-distribution</artifactId>
          <version>${alfresco.version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!--
No more repos are needed since they will be inherited by the parent POM. 
This is needed to download the alfresco-plaftorm POM.
-->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco-artifacts</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco-artifacts-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
  <modules>
<module>amp</module>
<module>alfresco</module>
<module>solr</module>
<module>share</module>
<module>wcmqs</module>
<module>runner</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

and here is the subpom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>
<name>Alfresco Repository and Explorer Client</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>Alfresco Repository and Explorer Client</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>nz.net.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dept-alfresco</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
     <!--
     <dependency> 
        <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     -->
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!--  Here is can control the order of overlay of your (WAR, AMP, etc.) dependencies
                    | NOTE: At least one WAR dependency must be uncompressed first
                    | NOTE: In order to have a dependency effectively added to the WAR you need to 
                    | explicitly mention it in the overlay section.
                    | NOTE: First-win resource strategy is used by the WAR plugin
                     -->
                <overlays>
                    <!-- Current project customizations -->
                    <overlay />
                    <!-- The Alfresco WAR -->
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <!-- To allow inclusion of META-INF -->
                        <excludes />
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: you might want to paste the output of `ls` or `find ./target` after running `mvn install` so I can see exactly what you mean.

Comment: In this case you can use `<finalName>xyz.war</finalName>` which will only fix the name in the target folder but not for installation via `mvn install`.

Comment: I tried stripVersion in the configuration of the alfresco pom, but it said it was an invalid element. I've tried finalName before and still don't get the right artefacts in Jenkins. Is there a system property I can add (-D on the maven options in Jenkins) to get it not to suffix the version number in the artefacts?

Answer (score 0):

(You should probably pastebin your pom.xml for a better answer...) but this is a "first effort/best guess"

If you are using `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy the libs into your workspace, you can strip off the version with a configuration option.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
              <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
          <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>        <-------here
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```